# 2D array from text file in excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am opening a text file which contains text like this

```
asdf,zxcv,asdwqe,asdh,we5,dvsew,safhc
asdf8,asdf3,asdf4,asdf5,asdf6,asdf7,asdf2
....
```

I am trying to put this all into a 2d array, the only way I have been able to do anything with this so far is to read the file line by line and split that line with a comma into a 1D array and use the information that way. But I have no idea how I'm supposed to do this with a 2D array, I have googled and have found nothing that is helpful.
is there a way I can put my 1d array into a 2d array or something?

Also I do not know how many strings there are per line(but all lines will have the same amount) nor how many lines there are in the file.

EDIT: To clarify, how I want it to work is for example if I do `MsgBox myArray(1,3)` I want *"asdf5"* to be displayed in that message box.

Comment: what data  will be in the second  dimension?

Comment: the "..." represents numerous other lines in the file, I'm not sure what you mean by the data in the second dimension but following my example, if I used myArray(1,3) I want to be able to retrieve the string "asdf5"

Comment: Could you post what you have so far, saves reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
Sub arrayTest()

    Dim arrData
    Dim wbtemp      As Workbook


    '/ 2 = Comma (format parameter)

    Set wbtemp = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.txt", False, True, 2)

    '/ Read in Array. range array is always 2D
    arrData = wbtemp.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    wbtemp.Close (0)

    '/ Range array will always start from 1. No 0 base,
    '/ but given how less code one needs to write, its a fair trade off.

    MsgBox arrData(2, 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! this works great, is there a way to disable the workbook that pops up for a split second from appearing?

Comment: Look into application.screenupdating

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: Don't use parentheses unless you are expecting a return value.  wbtemp.Close False